# How to know if it is unsigned of a field from mysql by MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-python

I use [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html)(a python library) to talk with mysql. Is there some way to get the field type using MySQLdb , and the most important thing is how can I know it is unsigned or not ?

I know we can use MYSQL_FIELD struct to get what I mentioned above using mysql C api. Is there something similar in MySQLdb ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the field type from the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html), e.g.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
```

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no provision in MySQLdb (not even via `_mysql`) for calling [`mysql_fetch_fields()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-fetch-fields.html). You will either have to patch it in, get someone else to do it, or find some way to do it in SQL.